# How to clip the amplitude of a wav file?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to detect the pitch of a signal by using an auto-correlation function with a clipping function.
I'm having trouble coding the clipping function.

I tried this:

```
[sig Fs]= wavread('sound.wav');

N = length(sig);

for i=1:N
    if sig > cl
        sigp(i) = sig(i)-cl(i);

    elseif sig < -cl
        sigp(i) = sig(i)+cl(i);
    else
        sigp(i) = 0;
end
```

However, when I try to plot the clipped part, the program is slow, and returns a blank plot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to index the sig array in the conditional statement. See below:

```
[sig Fs]= wavread('sound.wav');

N = length(sig);

for i=1:N
    if sig(i) > cl
        sigp(i) = sig(i)-cl;
    elseif sig(i) < -cl
        sigp(i) = sig(i)+cl;
    else
        sigp(i) = 0;
end
```

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question, and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @Sams Great! Please don't forget to accept my answer, if it was what you needed. Cheers!